# Fixing setTimeout in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am trying to port [this](https://codepen.io/manikantag/pen/qdeELg) code snippet to Coffee from JS, but getting stuck at the set timeout function which ignores the code, no classes are getting added on timeout at all:

```
$ ->

  $('.click').click ->
    $span = $(this).closest('span')
    $this = $(this)

    if $span.hasClass('fa-star')

      $this.removeClass 'active'

      setTimeout (->
        $this.removeClass 'active-2'
      ), 30

      $this.removeClass 'active-3'

      setTimeout (->
        $span.removeClass 'fa-star'
        $span.addClass 'fa-star-o'
      ), 15

    else

      $this.addClass 'active'
      $this.addClass 'active-2'

      setTimeout (->
        $span.addClass 'fa-star'
        $span.removeClass 'fa-star-o'
      ), 150

      setTimeout (->
        $this.addClass 'active-3'
      ), 150
```

Tried extracting the function but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the issue seems to be just with the jQuery code.

This looks wrong for the html you have.

```
$span = $(this).closest('span')
```

Change it to

```
$span = $(this).children().first()
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/kjxobowj/)

Comment: unfortunately, no effect

Comment: @TheWhizofOz Well the issue seems to be just with the jQuery code.

Comment: `$(this).find('.fa')` or `$(this).find('span.fa')` might be more robust choices. Probably doesn't matter that much though.